# Why do the leaves on my Kentia palm have dark spots?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, leaves, palm, damage

My kentia palm has begun having some dark spots which have already damaged some leaves. Can you give me some advice about it? I may have bad luck with kentias, because I like them very much but I have problems with them every time.

[image: kentia1]
[image: kentia2]

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Is this the same plant in your other question about a dying kentia? Did anything in that answer work for you? Were you able to save that one?  If this is a different plant, have you checked for insects, mold, etc.? Have you made any changes to the soil, amount of light, size of pot or any of those types of things? Hopefully someone can help you have more success growing this type of plant!

Answer (score 1):

The spots are caused by virus/fungus/bacteria.  They are opportunistic and only get a hold in a plant that has been overwatered in low light. Prevention is:

- move to higher light
- water less
- as a test remove plant from pot and check for soggy black roots which is a sign of root rot.  If found remove damaged roots and pot up in one size smaller pot